# Vue / Nuxt window.open button click event

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a button click event in Vue that calls a method to open a pdf using window.open(). It works fine in every browser except for safari on MAC. Not really sure what could be causing this? Do I need to pass $event to the method?

```js
 <div class="button-download">
  <button
    class="button button--primary__small"
    @click="openPDF"
  >
    Take Survey
  </button>
</div>


methods: {
  openPDF: () => {
    window.open("take-survey.pdf", "_blank");
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked this Website: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/mouse-event-handlers-arent-working-in-safari-macos-big-sur/117454

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it does not work with Safari specifically, it is more of a browser support issue and not your code specifically.

You may need to narrow down the issue to check where this one is coming from, tools like [Browserstack](https://www.browserstack.com/) can help to find out the version from which it may work again.

Then, it comes down to see if you can find a polyfill to replicate the unsupported snippet of code.